# Schengen visa query-place of issue

Tags: visas, schengen

I have a Schengen visa stamped on my passport from France.

The place of issue is Dubai (mentioned on the visa).

I had applied for it with my earlier Dubai Residency visa, however now it is cancelled and I am back in India. But my Schengen visa is still intact.

So the question is can I travel to the desired schengen country from India rather than from Dubai (rest of the itinerary remains unchanged).

There can be two ways:

1. I cancel my preciously booked ticket from Dubai to France and get a new ticket from India to France
2. I take a flight from India to Dubai (transit visa) and catch the same flight from Dubai to France

Answer (score 4):

You're supposed to apply for a visa in the place where you live *when applying*.

However, once you have the visa, there's no requirement that you enter the Schengen area directly from the place where you applied -- it's valid at all the external Schengen borders and for all anyone knows you could be on a longer itinerary.

Comment: Thanks Buddy, so that means even though place of issue is dubai, I can travel from india to the desired schengen country. This being my first visit to schengen post the visa issuance.

Comment: @Rajat: Yes -- typically when you arrive at an airport in the Schengen area, the border guard won't even know which plane you stepped off from -- all arriving out-of-Schengen passengers will be herded towards one single immigration control line.

Comment: (Note that you don't have to arrive into Schengen through France even though the French issued your visa -- you can pick any entry point, such as a flight connection in Frankfurt, Amsterdam, or Helsinki if that matches your plans better).

Comment: ya i get that budy.. th eonly thing that is worrying me is if there can be an issue from where I am boarding the flight. the place of visa issue is Dubai-as mentioned on the visa (this would be my first visit to europe), however i will be travelling from India to france and that is what is worrying me in case the immigration in india asks me " Mr. you visa was issued in dubai, why are you not travelling from Dubai?"..you get my point

Comment: @Rajat: The point is that the border guard _doesn't even know_ where you're traveling from. He may guess that you _probably_ arrived on one of the 20 different flights that arrived over the last hour, but he doesn't worry about such things.

Comment: Also, suppose your plan had be all the time to travel Dubai -> India -> Europe -> Dubai. In that case what you should so was _still_ to get the visa issued by the consulate/embassy in Dubai -- the place of issue should be "where you live" (at the time of issue), not "the previous country on your itinerary". There is no restriction on where one can arrive from with a given visa.

Comment: ok lemme explain. 1) I applied for schengen visa when I was working in dubai and had a dubai resident visa stamped on my passport(which was one of the impt documents for applying for schengen visa). At that time my itinerary was Dubai -France-Spain-Dubai. However, now I have left that job and have gotten my dubai resident visa cancelled and i am back india, hence my concern is whether indian immigration will ask about this place of issue for schengen visa and create hassle?

Comment: @Rajat: Sorry, didn't notice that. I have no idea what _Indian_ immigration would say or do, but I have difficulty imagining why they would even care about a visa for _somewhere else_. India is not part of Schengen.

Comment: hi ..can we have a quick chat on gmail? rajat.prakash17@gmail.com